# Find whether a string data is encoded in json or plist

Tags: c++, json, string, plist

When dealing with both json and plist, is there a way to find whether the incoming data is plist or json easily? or do i have to poke around the input data to find the same?

Comment: Use existing libraries to parse the data and see if that call succeeds.

Comment: that is the easiest way. but not always optimal as we have to intialize each parser, then check with a json parser and then with a plist parser to see whether the data is json or plist and when one of them succeeds, continue..